# how to call a new activity using a new thread in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am about to call a new activity but I want it to be opened in a new thread instead of the same thread. Please can any one help me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot open an Activity on a new thread, as an Activity has a UI and all UI work *must* be done on the main thread.

Instead, you could off load certain processing, networking etc. tasks onto background threads or into AsyncTasks.

Comment: can I open a new service in a new thread

Comment: Service's also launch onto the Main UI thread. You can however start a new Thread within the service and do your work on it.

Comment: so is it impossible to open a new service from a new thread other than MAIN UI thread..?

Comment: Even if you open it *from* a new thread, the service itself will launch *into* the main UI thread

Comment: so what is the use of using service instead of activity

Comment: That is completely unrelated to your question, and you should really use Google to get a proper understanding, but in short: A service is like an Activity, but without a UI